# ambiguous overload for 'operator!=' issue

Tags: c++, atl, mingw-w64

I am porting some ATL based headers into Mingw and came across problem with this code

```
    CComBSTR bstrHelpFile; 
        hr = pTypeLib->GetDocumentation(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, &bstrHelpFile);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && bstrHelpFile != NULL)
        {
           ..
        }
```

The error message that I get is this

```
C:\mingw64\opt\atlmfc\include/atlbase.h:5882:37: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'ATL::CComBSTR' and 'long long int')
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && bstrHelpFile != NULL)
                                     ^
C:\mingw64\opt\atlmfc\include/atlbase.h:5882:37: note: candidates are:
C:\mingw64\opt\atlmfc\include/atlbase.h:5882:37: note: operator!=(BSTR {aka wchar_t*}, BSTR {aka wchar_t*}) <built-in>
```

This is the code from the ATL header `atlbase.h`

Any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue ?

Comment: Yup that did it. Dont know why that was becoming a problem ?

Comment: `NULL` is not a very good null pointer. That's why we have `nullptr`.

Comment: Could you put that down as an answer so I could close this question.

Comment: Shoot, `nullptr` wouldn't even help here anyway. It's the way the class is designed that's causing ambiguity.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to reproduce it [online](http://rextester.com/UHS21835)...

Comment: See if `CComBSTR` has a member function which indicates if it is an empty string or not.  (BSTR semantics are supposed to be that empty strings and null pointers are interchangeable)

Comment: @chris he is using mingw, not vc++

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Oh, I didn't notice, thanks.

Comment: @MistyD can you add a mingw tag

Comment: Well, until later, keep in mind that 0 can be converted to a pointer, `CComBSTR` takes a pointer in the constructor, and it also has an `operator BSTR` (which is a pointer).

Comment: I added a mingw 64 bit tag

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem is in multiple versions of `operator !=` in `CComBSTR` class. Most likely your preferred way of fixing/resolving this problem is use of `CComBSTR.Length()` member function:

```
if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && bstrHelpFile.Length())
{
    // ...
```

The reason is that `NULL` is valid value for `BSTR` and if you want to check if the string is empty, you need to take into consideration the value can be both null pointer and valid pointer to zero length string.